# My upvoted question getting no interactions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A few months back, I wrote this question: [How can I compact my Scrap Mechanic logic down?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384003/how-can-i-compact-my-scrap-mechanic-logic-down). It has since (at the time of writing) gotten 3 upvotes, and a hundred views.

I have put two bounties on the question (100 rep, 50 rep), yet haven't gotten even a single interaction from other users.

What should I do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's entirely possible that nobody who actively uses the site knows the answer to your question. If that's the case, there's not much you can do on this site to address that. Your next most effective recourse is probably to ask elsewhere. You can link people back to your question here if you want with the "Share" link.

It looks to me like answering that question requires some deep game knowledge, because you're talking about doing a complicated bit of computer engineering within the game. And Scrap Mechanic isn't one of the more popular games on this site, as evidenced by the fact that yours is the only question about it.

Comment: Don't forget, if you do find the answer to your question elsewhere, come back and share it with us! You can answer your own questions, and this might help another player who comes along with the same question, later.

Comment: Given though that this game is still Early Access according to steam, I'm not entirely surprised. (I'll buy it when it's released, but not before.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It's been early access for years, and I wouldn't expect that to change any time soon. I honestly don't know why they haven't released it yet, as there are very few game-breaking bugs/glitches, and there are already so many mods and such. Given how many years it's been in early access, I wouldn't wait.